# Converting NSString data into the JSON format

Tags: ios, json, web-services, nsdictionary, contacts

Here is my response of contacts mobile number and name

```
2015-12-31 13:39:58.563 LCall[1448:53537] 888-555-1212
2015-12-31 13:39:58.563 LCall[1448:53537] John Appleseed
2015-12-31 13:39:58.564 LCall[1448:53537] (415) 555-3695
2015-12-31 13:39:58.565 LCall[1448:53537] Kate Bell
2015-12-31 13:39:58.565 LCall[1448:53537] 555-522-8243
2015-12-31 13:39:58.565 LCall[1448:53537] Anna Haro
2015-12-31 13:39:58.566 LCall[1448:53537] (408) 555-3514
2015-12-31 13:39:58.566 LCall[1448:53537] Daniel Higgins
2015-12-31 13:39:58.567 LCall[1448:53537] 555-610-6679
2015-12-31 13:39:58.567 LCall[1448:53537] David Taylor
2015-12-31 13:39:58.568 LCall[1448:53537] (707) 555-1854
2015-12-31 13:39:58.568 LCall[1448:53537] Hank Zakroff`
```

I want to convert their mobile number in below form

```
{"contacts":["+918146411786","8528840200"]}
```

or JSON format.

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to JSON? Is it just a one-off conversion? Or will you be doing this regularly? If the former, you could use regular expressions in a text editor like Notepad++. In the latter case, I would write a small program to do it. If you are parsing these results from a web service, then you will need to take several steps with string processing to get to the JSON you require.

Comment: oak i want to pass this result to a web services then what are the step

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
-(void)parseResultsString:(NSString *)input into:(NSString *)output {
    int phoneNumberStartingIndex = 40;
    NSMutableString* result = @"{\"contacts\":[";

    NSCharacterSet *separator = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
    NSArray *rows = [input componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separator];
    int counter = 0;
    NSString *comma = @"";

    for (NSString* line in rows) {
        if(counter % 2 == 0) { // Skip every 2nd line
            NSString *number = [line substringFromIndex:phoneNumberStartingIndex];
            [result appendFormat:@"%@\"%@\"", comma, number];
            comma = @",";
        }
    }
    [result appendString@"]}"];
    output = result;
}
```

The above makes some assumptions, (1) that the format of the input will always mean that the phone number is in the exact same position for each line, and (2) that the format will always mean that the phone number is only on the odd number lines.

If you need to parse the numbers into a certain format, then you could add another function to format the number before you append it to the result string.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my assumptions (it should not be necessary to make any assumptions when answering a question):

1. The initial data is contained in an array with name1, number1, name2, number2, etc.
2. You want to extract the numbers and put them into a dictionary with "contacts" as the key and the value as an array of numbers.
3. You want to format the dictionary into JSON for sending off somewhere.

---

```
NSArray *namesAndNumbers = ...;
NSAssert(([namesAndNumbers count] & 1) == 0, @"Input array has odd number of elements");
NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < [namesAndNumbers count]; i += 2) {
    [numbers addObject:namesAndNumbers[i]];
}
NSDictionary *contacts = @{ @"contacts" : numbers };
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:containts
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
if (jsonData) {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // Do something with string
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to format JSON: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```